# Difference between DIGITAL USER EXPERIENCE and USER EXPERIENCE

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-research, ux-field, ux-designer

What is the difference between DIGITAL USER EXPERIENCE and USER EXPERIENCE?

I'm wondering if DIGITAL UX actually exists further than a term itself?

Answer (score 2):

The difference to me is the specificity.

"User Experience" is more broad than "Digital UX". UX is not necessarily a purely digital field, it has applications in product design, exhibition design, industrial design, etc. Any time a user interacts with a system or object, "user experience" comes into play, regardless of whether it is digital/computerized or not.

"Digital UX" is more focused on digital products like apps, websites, games, human-computer interaction, and computer interfaces. It is a subset of user experience, and is usually what people think of when they hear "UX", but they're not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Iterms of heirarchy - broad to narrow: Customer Experience (CX) > User Experience (UX) > Digital User Experience